# Video capture using Opencv through single port multi-head (stereo) usb camera giving single output

Tags: python, c++, opencv, stereo-3d

I have recently bought a stereo camera through [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VG32EC2) and I want to use it for depth mapping. The problem is that the output that I get from the camera is in the form of a single video with the output of both the cameras.

[image: Camera output]

What I want is two seprate outputs from the single usb port if it is possible.I can use cropping but I dont want to use that because i am trying to reduce the processing time and I want the outputs sepratley.

The obove image was generated from the following code

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2

  cam = cv2. VideoCapture(1)
  cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 120)

  cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
  cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

  while(1):
  s,orignal = cam.read()
  cv2.imshow('original',orignal)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('w'):
  break


  cam.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have also tried other techniques such as:

```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2


  left = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
  right = cv2.VideoCapture(2)


  left.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 720)
  left.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
  right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
  right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

  left.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"))
  right.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"))

  # Grab both frames first, then retrieve to minimize latency between cameras
  while(True):
  _, leftFrame = left.retrieve()
  leftWidth, leftHeight = leftFrame.shape[:2]
  _, rightFrame = right.retrieve()
  rightWidth, rightHeight = rightFrame.shape[:2]

  # TODO: Calibrate the cameras and correct the images

  cv2.imshow('left', leftFrame)
  cv2.imshow('right', rightFrame)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break

  left.release()
  right.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but they are not recognising the 3rd camera any help would be nice.

My openCV version is 3.4

P.S If anyone can present a soloution in c++ it would also work for me

Comment: Have you had a read through this blog post https://albertarmea.com/post/opencv-stereo-camera/.

Comment: Smells like premature optimization (and I'm hesitant to even call it that). Most likely all you need is to grab two ROIs, which has negligible cost. Even if you had to copy the two halves, the cost will be quite trivial compared to any meaningful processing. | I'd say focus on the important part, the processing. When you've got that working and your measurements identify image acquisition as a bottleneck, you can always come back and try to improve it.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks, I added cropping to my code and it had a negligible effect, in fact, it was faster than using two separate cameras because that increases the whole image pipeline processing time. here we only have one image to process so it considerably reduced my processing time

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking :) Plus, you know the two views are as well synchronized as they can be with given hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after analysing the problem I figured that the best way would be to crop the images in half as it saves processing time. If you have two different image sources then your pipeline time is doubled for getting these images. After testing the stereo camera using cropping and without cropping I saw no noticeable change in the FPS. Here is a simple code for cropping the video and displaying it in two different windows.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cam = cv2.  VideoCapture(1)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 120)

cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
s,orignal = cam.read()
height, width, channels = orignal.shape
print(width)
print(height)
while(1):
    s,orignal = cam.read()
    left=orignal[0:height,0:int(width/2)]
    right=orignal[0:height,int(width/2):(width)]
    cv2.imshow('left',left)
    cv2.imshow('Right',right)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('w'):

        break


cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[[image: Left Image]

[image: Right Image]